# Rendering Large HTML Pages

Tags: javascript, java, html, json

I am currently write large data to html for some periodic reporting reasons . It has just a table with about 10,000 rows . Which are getting large as 7MB . When users open it sometimes browser becomes unresponsive cause of large file .

I can store JSON on server and later on when people load page get that JSON and page through and show 1000 records at a time.

What is better approach to implement this ?

Comment: The bare minimum is: do not load the page with all the data :)
As said above, ensure a pagination and a search control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make the following assumptions

1. the data is stored in a file
2. the data will only be appended to

If that is true, you can implement paging on the file. Use a random acces file. Simply read the file line by line for a number of records. Then when you are done, save the file `position`. When sending the html data to the browser also save the file position. This can be done using  query parameter in a link to "get more data".

When the user clicks the "get more data" link, you reopen the file, but first `position()` to the saved position. Then read the next few records, save the position etc.